# How to use join using One-to-Many relationship in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, relational-database, laravel-5.5

I have two tables `country` and `state`.
The country table has the columns `country_id` and `country_name`.
The state table has the columns `state_id`, `state_name` and `country_id`.

**I want to display `state_id`, `state_name` and `country_name` in the output.**

`Country` model:

```php
class Country extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'country';
    protected $fillable = ['country_name'];
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'country_id';

    public function state()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(State::class);
    }
}
```

`State` model:

```php
class State extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'state';
    protected $fillable = ['state_name','country_id'];
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'state_id';

    public function country()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
    }
}
```

My `StateController` is:

```php
$country_state_data = State::with('country_name')->get();
```

Comment: I edited your question and changed the casing of some class names. Please make sure you do use `PascalCase` for class names (i.e. first letter capital and the first letter of each word capital, i.e. `StateController`). You had some inconsistency in your code, which will lead to warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there already. What you want to do is use `State::get()` to get a list of all states. Then you add `with('country')` before `get()` so that it is added to the query builder. As you can see, `country` is the name of the relationship you want to eager load. After that you can access all properties of the `country` just like you can access the ones of your `state`:

```
$states = State::with('country')->get();
foreach ($states as $state) {
    echo "ID: {$state->id}, State: {$state->name}, Country: {$state->country->name}";
}
```

will output something like

```
ID: 1, State: Vorarlberg, Country: Austria
ID: 2, State: Bavaria, Country: Germany
```

---

After some investigation it seems that when changing the primary key, it makes sense to add keys to the relationship definition:

```
public function country()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Country::class, 'country_id', 'country_id');
}
```

Otherwise, the relationship does not get loaded properly.

Comment: only {$state->country_id works, but $state->country_name does not work.

Comment: Because `country_id` is a foreign key and present on the `state` table. If you want `country_name`, you have to use `{$state->country->country_name}`. That is by the way why you do not use the class name as prefix for each column - it doesn't read very well. It makes much more sense when you read `{$state->country->name}`, right?

Comment: {{ $state->country->country_name }}, this creates error ;Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Is it possible that not all of your states have a (**valid**) `country_id` assigned?

Comment: i checked, row in state table has valid country_id, if i run this query on database, its working fine. SELECT state_id,state_name,country_name FROM country,state WHERE country.country_id=state.country_id

Comment: That doesn't really tell you whether you have states with an invalid `country_id` or not. Try to run this one, it will list all states which have an invalid `country_id`: `SELECT * FROM state WHERE country_id NOT IN (SELECT country_id FROM country)`

Comment: this query returned zero rows,Can I contact you on facebook ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172775/discussion-between-namoshek-and-sarita-sharma).

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$country_state_data = state::with('country')->get();
```

and in your view

```
@foreach($country_state_data as $state)
    {{ $state->country->country_name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: this is not returing country name. i want to display country name also.

Comment: {{ $state->country->country_name }}, this creates error ;Trying to get property of non-object